# query a named single cell range vba

Tags: vba

I am trying to select a single cell value in an excel spreadsheet named "AtwickShortfall" as follow

```
StrSql = "SELECT  AtwickShortfall FROM [" & Glob_WsheetNameTradeLogOpsActions & "$AtwickShortfall]"
```

obviously does not work; can someone tell me the correct syntax ?

AtwickShortfall cell value is the sum of other values in the speadsheet; there are no tables in this spreadsheet at all.

**UPDATE 1**

tried this syntax

```
StrSql = "SELECT [AtwickShortfall]  FROM [" & Glob_WsheetNameTradeLogOpsActions & "$]"
```

I get an error "*No value given for one or more required parameters*"

**UPDATE 2**

after amending my code as per @Dick Kusleika answer I now have this code

```
StrSql = "SELECT * FROM [AtwickShortfall]" ' & Glob_WsheetNameTradeLogOpsActions & "$AH34]"
   
   Debug.Print (StrSql)

   Set RecSet = ConnObj.Execute(StrSql)

   If Not (RecSet Is Nothing) Then
      With RecSet
         If Not (.BOF) And Not (.EOF) Then
            Debug.Print RecSet.Fields(0).Value
            Else
              'UdtKpi.HornInjMeterSum = 0
            End If
         End If
      End With
   End If
```

no errors but the recodset is empty (BOF is true); the value of AtwickShortfall is a formula that gives 0 at the moment. I also tried to remove the formula and fill the cell with 0 but same result: recordset BOF is true

**UPDATE 3**

I found a solution but please have a look at the screenshot below

[image]

cell AtwickShortfall  is the one that I have now added a value of 125 on the column AH why this code work ?

```
StrSql = "SELECT Atw FROM [Operational_Actions$AH33:AH34]"
```

why it recognize the "atw" as a header of the range I gave??
If I change the above query to

```
StrSql = "SELECT Atw FROM [Operational_Actions$AH34:AH34]"
```

I get an epty recordset; It does not make sense how excel works to me; note that I have not implemented the worksheet data, it has been given to me

Comment: Notice in my connection string that I've set header to NO. See if yours is set to YES or NO. Maybe if it's set to YES, and the named range is a single cell, it thinks the cell is the header and doesn't return a record.

Comment: Hi Dick, yes that was the issue, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because the named range is at the workbook level (rather than worksheet level) that you can't specify what worksheet it's on. It's looking for a worksheet level named range when you specify the worksheet. This worked for me.

```
Sub getcell()
    
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\99991-dc01\99991\dkusleika\My Documents\testadonamedrange.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO"";"

    Set rs = cn.Execute("select * from [AtwickShortfall]")
    
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Value
    
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Dick, I applied your changes and there is some progress (no errors) but an empty recordset. The value of the cell I am looking for is 0 (zero) but I think I should get a record in the recordset; is because of teh select * maybe?